# MongoDB - How to perform a $match inside $switch statement

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I want to perform a search inside a `$switch` in an aggregation query. I want to hold a variable and change it according to the data from the front end. if that variable **"com"** I want to perform a search. On simple words, I can describe it as follows,

```js
let search = "com"
if (search == "com") {
  $match{
     com: {$regex: "search_data"}}
}
```

This is how I tried to perform the task:

```
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $eq: ['$search', 'com']
              },
              then: {
                com: { $regex: "serch_data" }
              }
            },
         ],
         default: {}
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `$search`, but `case: { $eq: ['com', search ] }`. `$search` refer to field in document.

And use `$regexMatch` operator, `$regex` operator doesn't support in aggregation pipeline.

```
{
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $switch: {
        branches: [
          {
            case: {
              $eq: [
                "com",
                search // search variable
                
              ]
            },
            then: {
              $regexMatch: {
                input: "$com",
                regex: "serch_data"
              }
            }
          },
          
        ],
        default: {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T8oRazzevyo)

Comment: Thank you for the respond @Yong Shun ,this works fine for me but what if com is a object array how to search name inside the object array com:[{name:a,des:aaaa},{name:b,des:"aa"}]

Comment: Perhaps this meets your requirement: [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5SwDOc_WtCF)

Comment: Thank you very much again @Yong Shun.One final question I want to do this inside switch                                                                                                                                 $match{
  $or: [{ name: /"a"/ },
  { com: /"a"/ }, {
    com: {
      $elemMatch: { name: /"a"/ }

    }
  }]

}

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't get your question about the latest comment. If you face any issue, welcome to create another question for it as the current answer is designed for the original question. It's hard to provide an **accurate** answer if you keep changing requirements and didn't provide the exact info/data. This is a kindly reminder when you write a new question. Thanks.

Comment: hi friend @young Shun i have add my question here  to make it more clear to you 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72337052/how-to-perform-a-match-with-or-inside-switch-statement-in-mongo)