# How to perform a $match with $or inside $switch statement in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, nosql-aggregation

Hi I am trying to get multiple searches inside switch so i want to do if one of the following **user:search_data||com:search_data||fruit:serch_data**  matches return search results.
i want to do,

```
$match:{
          $or:[{ user:{$regex:"search_data"}},
          {com:{$regex:"search_data"}},
          {fruit:{$elemMatch: {name:{$regex:"search_data"}}}}
}
```

this is a  search if user it should search user, if com it should search company I have able to do that now i want when we gives all if search data exits on user *OR* Com *OR* fruit it should return the search results

```
   {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $switch: {
                  branches: [
                    {
                      case: {
                        $eq: ['$search', 'all']
                      },
                      then: {
                       
                       //to this
                      }
                    },
                 ],
                 default: {}
              }
            }
          }
```

sample data

```
 user:"rithuwa",
  com:"abc",
  fruit:[{name:"mango",des:"aaaaa"},{name:"mango",des:"nnnn"}]
```

sample input

```
search_data:"rit"---->since this is in user it should output the record
search_data:"mango"--->since it in the fruit.name it should output the record
search_data:"ab"---->since it in the com it should output the record
search_data:"me"---->since it not in user,com or fruit should not give search record
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample input documents and expected output? Thanks.

Comment: I have update the post please check @Yong Shun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- if type is all check the regex in all
- else check in each based on type

*you know the type before sending the query, so you can do this switch case on application code, and have 4 queries, so based on the type to send one of them (the bellow does this on the server and query is bigger, you can do it with 4 much smaller queries)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=628a3f14853f039c69b0f8f2)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"searchData": "mango", "searchType": "tags"}},
 {"$match": 
   {"$expr": 
     {"$switch": 
       {"branches": 
         [{"case": {"$eq": ["$searchType", "all"]},
            "then": 
             {"$or": 
               [{"$regexMatch": {"input": "$name", "regex": "$searchData"}},
                 {"$regexMatch": {"input": "$company", "regex": "$searchData"}},
                 {"$reduce": 
                   {"input": "$tags",
                    "initialValue": false,
                    "in": 
                     {"$or": 
                       ["$$value",
                         {"$regexMatch": 
                           {"input": "$$this.name", "regex": "$searchData"}}]}}}]}},
           {"case": {"$eq": ["$searchType", "name"]},
            "then": 
             {"$regexMatch": {"input": "$name", "regex": "$searchData"}}},
           {"case": {"$eq": ["$searchType", "company"]},
            "then": 
             {"$regexMatch": {"input": "$company", "regex": "$searchData"}}},
           {"case": {"$eq": ["$searchType", "tags"]},
            "then": 
             {"$reduce": 
               {"input": "$tags",
                "initialValue": false,
                "in": 
                 {"$or": 
                   ["$$value",
                     {"$regexMatch": 
                       {"input": "$$this.name", "regex": "$searchData"}}]}}}}],
        "default": true}}}},
     {"$unset": ["searchData", "searchType"]}])
```

Comment: thank you for the support.I am trying to  use a switch cause we have search types if search type is user it shoud serch only users if search type is com  it should only search com if search type is fruit is should only saerch fruites.Luckily i have implemented up to this. When comming to the part of search type all i am struguling